# Assign Spring Security Roles in Grails based on SAML Response

Tags: spring, grails, spring-saml

I'm working with the [Spring Security SAML Grails Plugin](https://github.com/jeffwils/grails-spring-security-saml) in Grails 3.3.9. I've read the documentation but I don't understand how to assign roles to a user. I've previously used a combination of the Spring Security Core & LDAP plugins to authenticate users and am now switching to SAML to support Single-Sign-On. In the SAML documentation I see the need to set the following

```
Property    | Syntax    | Example Value | Description
userGroupAttribute  | String Value  | 'memberOf'|   Corresponds to the Role Designator in the SAML Assertion from the IDP
userGroupToRoleMapping  | Map [Spring Security Role: Saml Assertion Role]   | [ROLE_MY_APP_ROLE: 'CN=MYSAMLGROUP, OU=MyAppGroups, DC=myldap, DC=example, DC=com']   | This maps the Spring Security Roles in your application to the roles from the SAML Assertion. Only roles in this Map will be resolved.
```

In my code I have set these properties like this:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.saml.userGroupAttribute = 'Group'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.saml.userGroupToRoleMapping = [ROLE_USER:'CN=USERS,CN=Groups,DC=trknow,DC=com',
                                                            ROLE_ADMIN:'CN=ADMINS,OU=Groups,DC=trknow,DC=com']
```

I am using ADFS as my IDP and all attributes are being pulled out of Microsoft Active Directory. According to my idp xml file, the userGroupAttribute is named 'Group'.

```
<samlp:Response Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified"
    Destination="https://sso.trknow.com:8443/sammy/saml/SSO"
    ID="_59831374-4e0c-4664-8431-016293d16ecb" IssueInstant="2019-03-29T19:03:00.075Z" Version="2.0"
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://federation.trknow.com/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
    <samlp:Status><samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/></samlp:Status>
    <Assertion ID="_8a9e9831-1d74-4e74-a5ee-928f3739c663" IssueInstant="2019-03-29T19:03:00.074Z"
        Version="2.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        <Issuer>http://federation.trknow.com/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                <ds:Reference URI="#_8a9e9831-1d74-4e74-a5ee-928f3739c663">
                    <ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                    <ds:DigestValue>hAeKlB*Truncated*</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>Umiu*Truncated*</ds:SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>MIIC5*Truncated*</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </KeyInfo>
        </ds:Signature>
        <Subject>
            <NameID>john.willi</NameID>
            <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"><SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2019-03-29T19:08:00.075Z"
                Recipient="https://sso.trknow.com:8443/sammy/saml/SSO"/></SubjectConfirmation>
        </Subject>
        <Conditions NotBefore="2019-03-29T19:03:00.066Z" NotOnOrAfter="2019-03-29T20:03:00.066Z">
            <AudienceRestriction>
                <Audience>sso.sammy.com</Audience>
            </AudienceRestriction>
        </Conditions>
        <AttributeStatement>
            <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress">
                <AttributeValue>john.willi@trknow.com</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname">
                <AttributeValue>Williams</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname">
                <AttributeValue>John</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group">
                <AttributeValue>CN=ADMINS,OU=Groups,DC=trknow,DC=com</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid">
                <AttributeValue>CN=ADMINS,OU=Groups,DC=trknow,DC=com</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role">
                <AttributeValue>ROLE_ADMIN</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
        </AttributeStatement>
        <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2019-03-29T19:02:55.635Z"
            SessionIndex="_8a9e9831-1d74-4e74-a5ee-928f3739c663">
            <AuthnContext>
                <AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</AuthnContextClassRef>
            </AuthnContext>
        </AuthnStatement>
    </Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

I have debugging turned on for the saml plugin. When I authenticate I see that it says 0 authorities were assigned. What is going on?

```
2019-03-29 15:03:09.869 DEBUG --- [nio-8443-exec-9] o.g.p.s.s.SpringSamlUserDetailsService   : UserClass class sammy.User
2019-03-29 15:03:09.878 DEBUG --- [nio-8443-exec-9] o.g.p.s.s.SpringSamlUserDetailsService   : Generated User john.willi
2019-03-29 15:03:09.880 DEBUG --- [nio-8443-exec-9] o.g.p.s.s.SpringSamlUserDetailsService   : Loading database roles for john.willi...
2019-03-29 15:03:09.890 DEBUG --- [nio-8443-exec-9] o.g.p.s.s.SpringSamlUserDetailsService   : Returning Authorities with  0 Authorities Added
2019-03-29 15:03:09.890 DEBUG --- [nio-8443-exec-9] o.g.p.s.s.SpringSamlUserDetailsService   : User Class class sammy.User
2019-03-29 15:03:09.890 DEBUG --- [nio-8443-exec-9] o.g.p.s.s.SpringSamlUserDetailsService   : User - username john.willi
2019-03-29 15:03:09.890 DEBUG --- [nio-8443-exec-9] o.g.p.s.s.SpringSamlUserDetailsService   : User - id null
2019-03-29 15:03:09.902 DEBUG --- [nio-8443-exec-9] o.g.p.s.s.SpringSamlUserDetailsService   : User Details grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser@492ab3cb: Username: john.willi; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Not granted any authorities
```

Answer (score 0):

Check SpringSamlUserDetailsService and see how it adds GrantedAuthority. Is it using Group or Role element to add GrantedAuthority? Maybe it expects to have a group attribute as an element's name http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/Group instead of just "Group".